# How to process a payment in multiple stages in Paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

I have to apply Paypal API for payment in Multiple Staging

For Eg. the Seminar is booked on the 31st July for $1000. (the booking date)

A 20% deposit is required (which have to be paid instantly)

The Seminar date is December 20th 2017.
20% of 1000= $200 is required now (the booking date) on paypal.

Total Payable=$800.00

Stage payments = 5

Payment-1 AUG 1st 2017 -> $160.00

Payment-2 SEP 1st 2017 -> $160.00

Payment-3 OCT 1st 2017 -> $160.00

Payment-4 NOV 1st 2017 -> $160.00

Payment-5 DEC 1st 2017 -> $160.00

PS: The Seminar needs to be paid in total before it starts on the Seminar date.

Eg. if the Seminar started on the DEC 1 2017 only 4 stage payments would be allowed of $200.00. However If the Seminar start date is less than a month no stage payments are allowed and the full payment has to be done.

It's different than EMIs so I guess I can not use Paypal EMIs API, also I can't make subscription plans for each seminar.
I googled with a lot of keywords but I couldn't find anything. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You can use PayPal reference transactions for charging the buyer according to your requirement. Refer the below URL links for more information:

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1502

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/